# Measure Page Load Speed with Selenium upon Python script on real device

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to measure web page load speed with using Selenium and Python scripting.If the following driver is firefox or chrome in local (ubuntu 16.04) then seems working like a charm but if I use webdriver.Remote then performance responses are not working .

```
from selenium import webdriver
desired_caps = {}
desired_caps['platformName'] = 'Android'
desired_caps['deviceName'] = 't03g'
desired_caps['appPackage'] = 'com.android.chrome'
desired_caps['appActivity'] = 'com.google.android.apps.chrome.Main'
driver = webdriver.Remote('http://192.168.1.40:4723/wd/hub', desired_caps)
driver.get('https://www.bbc.com/')

responseStart = driver.execute_script("return window.performance.timing.responseStart")
domComplete = driver.execute_script("return window.performance.timing.domComplete")
frontendPerformance_calc = float(domComplete - responseStart) / 1000

print(frontendPerformance_calc)

driver.quit()
```

And the output of run is like :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "rasha.py", line 10, in <module>
    responseStart = driver.execute_script("return window.performance.timing.responseStart")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 636, in execute_script
    'args': converted_args})['value']
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Method is not implemented
```

Something is different I guess if we use real device but couldn't find it; Could you please help on that,

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question but I found an article that has ''Navigation Start'' before ''response start'' and ''dom Complete''
https://www.lambdatest.com/blog/how-to-measure-page-load-times-with-selenium/

On windows chrome it works like this for me:

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
driver.get('https://www.google.com')
driver.maximize_window()

#! Use Navigation Timing  API to calculate the timings that matter the most
navigationStart = driver.execute_script("return window.performance.timing.navigationStart")
responseStart = driver.execute_script("return window.performance.timing.responseStart")
domComplete = driver.execute_script("return window.performance.timing.domComplete")

#! Calculate the performance
backendPerformance_calc = responseStart - navigationStart
frontendPerformance_calc = domComplete - responseStart

print("Back End: %s" % backendPerformance_calc)
print("Front End: %s" % frontendPerformance_calc)
```